How to setup ubuntu host to provide internet for guests on private subnet?
As a developer I am trying to setup vm guests on ubuntu 22 host (virtualbox) to be able to reach the Internet. The twist is I am not running an external router on the same private subnet, so I suppose I also need to setup a "router/gateway" functionality on the host to properly connect the two worlds (?).
To give you a context, I am trying to migrate my current (old) setup, which is like this:
(Internet) <--> asus router (static public ip a.b.c.d, gateway + dhcp for internal subnet 192.168.84.1) <--> ubuntu host (192.168.84.107) <--> vm guests (192.168.84.xxx)
The configuration on the current (old) host is a simple bridge (encapsulating the physical eth0), gateway set to 192.168.84.1 (the asus router), everything works flawlessly.
My new host is located elsewhere (and it is a VM itself, so in fact I am doing a nested virtualization now, but I guess its not relevant to this question), got its own public ip (a.b.c.132/25) and using a remote gateway (a.b.c.129). Therefore there is no router 192.168.84.1 to point the vms (using 192.168.84.xxx) to:
(Internet) <--> external router (a.b.c.129) <--> ubuntu host (public IP a.b.c.132/25) <--> vm guests (192.168.84.xxx)
What I have tried (I will edit the question and provide netplan, ifconfig, ip route and other dumps if required, but for now I am merely asking if the thing I am trying to do is even possible):

edited netplan: removed all settings from the "eth0" interface, created bridge "br0" encapsulating it, and placed the settings there (addresses, nameservers, routes). I also added the ip 192.168.84.1 to the addresses, so now br0 got two ips (the original public a.b.c.132/25 and the subnet gateway's 192.168.84.1/24)

set the vm to use the bridged adapter (& assigned them static ips 192.168.84.x)

installed isc dhcp server and configured it to manage interface "br0" and subnet 192.168.84.0 (mask 255.255.255.0), using router 192.168.84.1


Current status:

a) host can reach the Internet
b) host can reach all guests (using their 192.168.84.x ips)
c) guests can reach other guests
d) guests can reach the host (using 192.168.84.1)
e) guests can NOT reach the Internet - ping even shows a "misconfigured" (?) interface (probably due to the fact br0 uses both the public and the internal gateway ips?):

From 192.168.84.1: icmp_seq=3 Redirect Host(New nexthop: a.b.c.129)
I assume I am missing a piece connecting the local dhcp/routing to the external gateway, but I am running out of ideas (and permutations) what to change where.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Thank you for taking your time reading my somewhat long post, yet I am not sure how does my question no meet the "how-to-ask" criteria (I am trying to be specific & descriptive) and/or how would more formatting help (apart from the letter bullet points, would be better to turn them to numbers?). Its a genuine question, not trying to be smart.

As its often the case, I was really close to the solution, the only missing piece was a NAT rule:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -4 -s 192.168.84.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

Adding this rule connects the guest VMs to the Internet, solving the issue.
Here's my full config for context:
netplan.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      set-name: eth0
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - eth0
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
      addresses:
        - a.b.c.132/25
        - 192.168.84.1/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: a.b.c.129

dhcpd.conf
subnet 192.168.84.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.84.102 192.168.84.200;
  option routers 192.168.84.1;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.84.255;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
}

isc-dhcp-server
INTERFACESv4="br0"

Hope that helps anyone.
